# Can you convert PDF relative links to hyperlinks with PHP

Tags: php, pdf

We have received thousands of PDFs to be hosted on our servers, and they all have links to other PDFs within the folder.  I've googled the problem, and generally find only that it's a common problem, or PDF libraries that don't mention anything like this.

Since we have to parse the text in the PDFs anyways, I'm wondering if anyone know how to identify a link within the PDF being processed by the PHP, change it to an HTTP link, then save it as a new PDF file.  I'm probably dreaming, but am hoping someone might know of a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[TCPDF](http://www.tcpdf.org/) is Good class for create pdf of html and text files and more...
with template and full documention
This question is posible in it